# pop up to graph startDestination fragment for a global action - Android navigation components

Tags: android, navigation, androidx, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I've a multi-graph navigation app and I'd like to switch between graphs by using a `global action` as defined in my root `main_graph.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_graph"
        app:startDestination="@id/loadingFragment">

    <include app:graph="@navigation/learn_graph" />

    <action
            android:id="@+id/action_global_learn_graph"
            app:destination="@id/learn_graph"
            app:launchSingleTop="true"
            />
</navigation>
```

Since I'm trying to switch between graphs, I'd like to clear the back stack from the fragments loaded by the source graph (main_graph) when navigating the global action to the destination graph (explore_graph). The expected behavior would be to navigate to the `startDestination` fragment of the destination graph keeping only that fragment in the backstack.
For normal actions (actions in the same graph) I'm able to use `popUpTo` flag, how it's possible to get the same behavior for a global action?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Let me know once you have figured it out.

Comment: @InsaneDeveloper probably I found a solution, check the answer below please ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After a lot of attemps, I found out a solution. The base idea is to pop up the backstack to the graph that "owns" the global action. In my case `main_graph` is the owner, so I did:

```xml
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_graph"
        app:startDestination="@id/loadingFragment">

    <include app:graph="@navigation/learn_graph" />

    <action
            android:id="@+id/action_global_learn_graph"
            app:destination="@id/learn_graph"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/main_graph"
            app:launchSingleTop="true" />

</navigation>
```

In addition, you have to set the `app:launchSingleTop` flag to `true` in order to make the instance of **destination graph** unique in your backstack

You can also include `app:popUpToInclusive="true"` to indicate that the destination specified in `app:popUpTo` should also be **removed** from the back stack.